# How to create a Pivot table in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a sponsorship app I'm creating and trying to get a pivot table working between my users and kids, but when I have a user sponsor a kid, the pivot table `kid_user` is not populated with the `kid_id` or the `user_id`. Not sure what I'm missing.

- A Kid can have as many users (sponsors) as their slots allow them.
- Users can sponsor a kid, multiple kids or the same kid multiple times
  if needed.

**Here is my `kid_user` pivot table:**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('kid_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('kid_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('kid_id')->references('id')->on('kids')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->primary(['kid_id', 'user_id']);
    });
}
```

**Then on the User model:** The user can have many kids...

```
public function kid()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Kid::class);
}
```

**Then on the Kid model:** The kids can have many users...

```
  public function user() {
      //return $this->belongsTo(User::class); (Tried this..)
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
  }
```

**Here are the tables I'm using.** (Only relevant info is included in the tables)

```
+---------------------+
| Tables_in_Database  |
+---------------------+
| kid_user            |
| kids                |
| users               |
+---------------------+

+-----------------------------+
|        users table          |
+----+------------+-----------+
| id | first_name | last_name |
+----+------------+-----------+
|  1 | John       | Smith     |
|  2 | Jane       | Doe       |
+----+------------+-----------+

+-----------------------------+
|        kids table           |
+----+------------+-----------+-------+
| id | first_name | last_name | slots |
+----+------------+-----------+-------+
|  1 | Bobby      | Little    |   3   | -> Can be sponsored 3 times
+----+------------+-----------+-------+

+--------------------+
|   kid_user table   | THE BELOW RESULTS ARE WHAT I'M LOOKING FOR.
+--------------------+
| *kid_id | *user_id | * = Primary Key
+---------+----------+
|    1    |     1    | -> Sponsored 1st Slot
+---------+----------+
|    1    |     2    | -> Sponsored 2nd Slot
+---------+----------+
|    1    |     1    | -> Sponsored 3rd Slot
+---------+----------+
```

So when a User sponsors a Kid. I would like the `kid_id` & `user_id` to be entered into the `kid_user` pivot table. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you might wanna rename the functions in your models in plural as it does not have one but many from the relationship.

So in your user model add this:

```
public function kids()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Kid::class);
}
```

And in your Kid model:

```
public function users()
{
     return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

Then in order to save to the pivot table since your table naming is correct, just doing:

```
$user->kids()->attach($kid);
```

Will save it properly in the pivot table. Making sure first that you have existing User and Kid for the variables. More details [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: Thanks for the plural tip on the functions. I was just reading about the `belongsToMany` and tried it out. Where do I add the `$user->kids()->attach($kid);` so I can save?

Comment: I don't know how you layer your application, where do you have the business logic. You can easily add that in your controller function. Just retrieve the `$kid` which you want to sponsor and I guess the currently authenticated user should be the one, so just simply `$kid = Kid::find(request('kid_id'));` then `auth()->user->kids()->attach($kid);`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent answer !