# How to fix Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-1' for key 'PRIMARY: Laravel Pivot Table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys

I have a sponsorship app and trying to add sponsor kids and users into a pivot table after the user sponsors the child.

- A Kid can have as many users (sponsors) as their ***slots*** allow them.
- Users can sponsor a single kid, multiple kids OR ***the same kid multiple times*** if needed.

I created a pivot table for sponsor kids and users. On the first transaction the relationship in the table is correct, but if the user goes back and sponsors the child again for the 2nd or 3rd slot I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '1-1' for key 'PRIMARY' (23000)

**`kid_user` pivot table:**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('kid_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('kid_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('kid_id')->references('id')->on('kids')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->primary(['kid_id', 'user_id']);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Kid Model:**

```
  public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withTimestamps();
  }
```

**User Model:**

```
  public function kids(){
       return $this->belongsToMany(Kid::class)->withTimestamps();
  }
```

Attaching in my controller with this line:

```
        $cin = $request->cin;
        $kidid = $request->kidid;

        $kids = DB::table('kids')->where('cin', $cin)->increment('sponsors_received');
        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->kids()->attach($kidid);
        //$user->kids()->sync($kidid);
;
```

**What I'm currently getting:**

```
+--------------------+
|   kid_user table   | 
+--------------------+
| *kid_id | *user_id | * = Primary Key
+---------+----------+
|    1    |     1    | -> Sponsored 1st Slot
+---------+----------+
```

**What I'm wanting to get:**

```
+--------------------+
|   kid_user table   | THE BELOW RESULTS ARE WHAT I'M LOOKING FOR.
+--------------------+
| *kid_id | *user_id | * = Primary Key
+---------+----------+
|    1    |     1    | -> Sponsored 1st Slot (CURRENTLY GETTING)
+---------+----------+
|    1    |     1    | -> Sponsored 2nd Slot (ERRORS HERE!!!)
+---------+----------+
|    2    |     1    | -> Sponsored 3rd Slot (THIS WILL WORK)
+---------+----------+
```

I've tried tried using `sync` rather than `attach` in my controller, but `sync` just overwrites the first relationship rather adding a new one to represent that the user is sponsoring the child's 1st and 2nd slot out of 3 slots.

Also tried using the `hasMany` relationship in my models, but that did not help.
As a last try, I also added the created/updated at columns in hopes that would make it unique, but no luck..

Comment: add your controller logic with sync.

Comment: updated question with your request. Above that is just stripe transaction logic.
This is really a follow-up question to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54153547/how-to-create-a-pivot-table-in-laravel/54153623?noredirect=1#comment95138440_54153623

Comment: kid_id should be foreign key (of kids table) instead of primary in kid_user table.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use a normal incrementing id for the kid_user table?  Your current primary is what's throwing the error.

Comment: The PRIMARY KEY constraint uniquely identifies each record in a table.

Primary keys must contain UNIQUE values, and cannot contain NULL values.

Comment: So kid_user table is just a relational table so there is no need to maintain primary key for incremental purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in database design. In your table the set of ('kid_id','user_id') must be unique. But second (1,1) in your example is wrong because there is already a set of (1,1).

If you want to let the same user sponsor "the same kid multiple times" then your approach will not work. You can use a distinct primary key for maintaining this constraint. In this case, it should be something like,

```
| pivot_id*| kid_id | user_id |  * = Primary Key
+---------+---------+----------+
|    1    |    1    |     1    | -> Sponsored 1st Slot (CURRENTLY GETTING)
+---------+---------+----------+
|    2    |    1    |     1    | -> Sponsored 2nd Slot (SAME DATA WITH DIFFERENT KEY)
+---------+---------+----------+
|    3    |    2    |     1    | -> Sponsored 3rd Slot (THIS WILL WORK)
```

Comment: Okay that makes sense. So in my kid_user table I should simply add an id column and remove the `$table->primary(['kid_id', 'user_id']);` ... Correct?

Comment: Yes. After that, Laravel should not show this error.

Comment: @NabilFarhan what is the main purpose of maintaining pivot_id in relational table? Can we achieve resolve it without adding this field?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I agree with @Nabil's answer. There is a problem with database design. Application is throwing error due to unique constrain in db tables. Either go with the approach he has suggested or you can add count field too. I assume, you want to know how many sponsorship a kid got? Make all those fields unique (kid_id, user_id, slots)

Comment: I was thinking about the slots column and might do that as I do have a slots_needed column in the kids table, but I think @Nabil's answer will work for my needs. Thanks for the feedback!